# Live camera is getting stretched while rendering using CIFilter. - Swift 4

Tags: ios, camera, arkit, cifilter, stretched

I want to apply camera filter while rendering, my code is...

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage)
        var r: CGFloat = 0, g: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0

        color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(CIVector(x: r, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
        filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: g, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
        filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: b, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
        filter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: a), forKey: "inputAVector")

        if let result = filter.outputImage,
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) {
            sceneView.scene.background.contents = cgImage
            sceneView.scene.background.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        }
}
```

at runtime, output is getting stretched. I have attached two images,

1. Normal Camera rendering
2. With filter camera rendering.

[image: This is normal camera rendering, it looks nice,]

[image: This is live camera with filter, you can see at runtime Live camera is getting stretched.]

Please help me to resolve it, it would be great help if you provide any demo code or project. Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen for all orientations, i.e., when you hold the phone sideways?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes it's happen for all orientations, I want to apply only for portrait mode.

Comment: Is it stretched in the same way on landscape? Or is it along the other axis?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel yes, it is stretched in the same way on landscape.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If you remove the contentsTransform line it looks normal when I move the orientation to landscape mode. Camera to the left.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to elaborate on Juan Boero answer, while what he is saying is completely true, it took me some time to figure out the solution, so for the people who came here later looking for a concrete approach to this problem here is what I've got:

When you use `capturedImage` of `ARFrame` you receive a `CVPixelBuffer` that is representing image oriented in landscape (because that's how iPhone's camera is taking it). 
If you're trying to transform this image to a normal orientation using

```
let transform = frame.displayTransform(
            for: screenOrientation,
            viewportSize: sceneView.bounds.size
).inverted()
let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage).transformed(by: transform)
```

You will get a stretched image because (at lease in my case) pixel buffer's dimensions are `1920x1440 (width x height)` and `sceneView.bounds.size` is `375x812 (height x width)`. So there is no way to normally fit a `1440x1920` into `375x812` because they are not compatible.

What you can actually do if you just need an image is to apply the transformation to the inverted dimensions of the pixel buffer:

```
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(frame.capturedImage)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(frame.capturedImage)
let transform = frame.displayTransform(
            for: screenOrientation,
            viewportSize: CGSize(width: height, height: width)
).inverted()
let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage).transformed(by: transform)
```

This way you will get a correctly rotated image with correct dimensions.

Then you can do whatever you want with it, e.g. crop to aspect-fit it into the scene view.

Comment: Just wanted to say this just saved me a bunch of time. Thanks, man! (Happens to be exactly one year later, too)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i recommend you make a copy of the `ARFrame`, otherwise `currentFrame` will get all sort of weirdness if not processed soon enough, because the memory will be discarded by the hardware.

Second, the stretching is because you are using the buffer image that is different from the viewport image, grab a `session.snapshot` and save it to you mac, and then grab your `cgImage` and save it too, open them in Preview, you will see the sizes differ, so, when you want to put that wider image back to the viewport size, it stretches.

You do not need a demo project for this one, just print your scene frame size, and your buffer size, check the ratios between both and you will understand your issue.